# Why tab space causes error in coffee script

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript

I am learning react with rails from [here](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers). On following tutorial I canme to this error 
`ExecJS::RuntimeError in Records#index
SyntaxError: [stdin]:41:13: cannot have an implicit value in an implicit object`

And then from little bit research on google, I came to know error is coming because of tab space.

Check this react js code:

```js
@RecordForm = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    title: ''
    date: ''
    amount: ''
  render: ->
    React.Dom.form
      className: 'form-inline'
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'form-group'
        React.DOM.input
          type: 'text'
          className: 'form-control'
          placeholder: 'Date'
          name: 'date'
          value: @state.date
          onChange: @handleChange

        React.DOM.div
          className: 'form-group'
          React.DOM.input
            type: 'text'
            className: 'form-control'
            placeholder: 'Title'
            name: 'title'
            value: @state.title
            onChange: @handleChange
        React.DOM.div
          className: 'form-group'
          React.DOM.input
            type: 'number'
            className: 'form-control'
            placeholder: 'Amount'
            name: 'amount'
            value: @state.amount
            onChange: @handleChange
        React.DOM.button
          type: 'submit'
          className: 'btn btn-primary'
          disabled: !@valid()
            'Create record'

  handleChange: (e) ->
    name = e.target.name
    @setState "#{ name }": e.target.value

        valid: ->
        @state.title && @state.date && @state.amount

  handleSubmit: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.post '', { record: @state }, (data) =>
      @props.handleNewRecord data
      @setState @getInitialState()
    , 'JSON'

  render: ->
    React.DOM.form
      className: 'form-inline'
      onSubmit: @handleSubmit
```

Removing the spaces before `'Create record'` from the above script will solve the problem. You can check it by this [utility(link)](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%40RecordForm%20%3D%20React.createClass%0A%20%20getInitialState%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20''%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20''%0A%20%20%20%20amount%3A%20''%0A%20%20render%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20React.Dom.form%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-inline'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.div%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-group'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.input%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'text'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-control'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholder%3A%20'Date'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'date'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%40state.date%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20%40handleChange%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.div%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-group'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.input%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'text'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-control'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholder%3A%20'Title'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'title'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%40state.title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20%40handleChange%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.div%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-group'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.input%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'number'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-control'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholder%3A%20'Amount'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'amount'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%40state.amount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20%40handleChange%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20React.DOM.button%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'submit'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'btn%20btn-primary'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20disabled%3A%20!%40valid()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Create%20record'%0A%0A%20%20handleChange%3A%20(e)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20name%20%3D%20e.target.name%0A%20%20%20%20%40setState%20%22%23%7B%20name%20%7D%22%3A%20e.target.value%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20valid%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40state.title%20%26%26%20%40state.date%20%26%26%20%40state.amount%0A%0A%20%20handleSubmit%3A%20(e)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20e.preventDefault()%0A%20%20%20%20%24.post%20''%2C%20%7B%20record%3A%20%40state%20%7D%2C%20(data)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40props.handleNewRecord%20data%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40setState%20%40getInitialState()%0A%20%20%20%20%2C%20'JSON'%0A%0A%20%20render%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20React.DOM.form%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20className%3A%20'form-inline'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20onSubmit%3A%20%40handleSubmit%0A)

Comment: Indentation defines the structure in CoffeeScript so you must be very careful and consistent with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare object in 2 ways and your compiler can't decide which of them you use.

The best way to avoid errors like yours is to choice one of the methods within each declaration.

```
# First way
obj =
  a : 1
  b : 2

# First way (compact)
obj = a : 1, b : 2

# Second way
# vars and props with same names (compact)
a = 1; b = 2
obj = {
  a
  b
}

# Second way (compact)
a = 1; b = 2
obj = {a, b}
```

You can also use [React JSX support for Coffeescript](https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-react-transform)

**update:**

Lets look closer to you code.

You can send two arguments like that.

```
React.DOM.button
  type      : 'submit'
  className : 'btn btn-primary'
  disabled  : !@valid()
  , 'Create record'
```

Or like that.
The combination of entering object and not object compiles into two arguments.

```
  type      : 'submit'
  className : 'btn btn-primary'
  disabled  : !@valid()
  'Create record'
```

[And what you do in your code](http://coffeescript.org/#try:React.DOM.button%0A%20%20type%3A%20'submit'%0A%20%20className%3A%20'btn%20btn-primary'%0A%20%20disabled%3A%20!%40valid()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22Create%20Record%22%0A%20%20%7D) Compiler try to send `Object {'Create record' : 'Create record'}` as argument into result of call `!@valid()`.

```
React.DOM.button
  type: 'submit'
  className: 'btn btn-primary'
  disabled: !@valid()
    'Create record'
```

Comment: I still didn't get why this doesn't works 

````
React.DOM.button
          type: 'submit'
          className: 'btn btn-primary'
          disabled: !@valid()
            'Create record'
````

But removing spaces before ```'Create record'``` works fine.

Comment: Check my initial post. Markdown's `` `` is not working in comment

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it now :)